# What is the use of List in ArrayAdapter constructor?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

Im curious to know why `List`(`ArrayList`) is passed to `ArrayAdapter` constructor `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)`. Because while overriding  `getView` method we will create `Class obj=getItem(position)` and that `obj` contains all the information of `List` which passed in constructor and can be retrieved by getter methods.

Whats the use List here?

Comment: It's better to create a new question than completely rewriting an existing one

Answer (score 2):

The ArrayAdapter is meant so that you **don't have to override any methods.**
The list is used to pull the items from. Each items will have it's *toString()* method called and that is displayed in a text view. The textview is inflated from the other arguments you pass to the constructor.

If you want to override the adapter methods such as *getView()* you can extend [BaseAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) instead.